# Mediawiki build a page from other pages content

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki

With Mediawiki I didn't manage to build a main page that would take information from a set of other pages from the wiki. Let's say each page have a status like "in progress", "done"... I would then like the main page to display a table of each page with its status.

How can I specify the status to each page so the main page would be able to grab this information and display the wanted table ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MediaWiki's (built-in) [template system](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates) ([quick intro](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aA_quick_guide_to_templates)).

You could create a template for the status of each page, containing just those words. You can include it then both in the main page, the subpage itself or any other place. To update the status, you'll need to edit the template.

Or you could use the pages themselves as templates. With the [`<onlyinclude>` syntax](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplate#Noinclude.2C_includeonly.2C_and_onlyinclude) you can tell the templating system to use only a single piece to tranclude in other pages, in here the status information. Including such a page will need the namespace in front, e.g. if it's in the default ("article") namespace without a prefix it would be `{{:Subpage}}`. This system is a bit more complicated, but you'd only need one edit to change both page and status. See also [Help:Advanced templates](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aAdvanced_templates).

Comment: That is a very brilliant use of templates, I never thought of them that way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, there might also be an extension to store & edit "status" information for each page, and build such tables automatically, but "*building a page from other pages content*" is just possible with templates... This even can be used to build high-level data storage systems, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Metadata

Comment: Thanks again mate, you've been of great help

Answer (score 2):

[Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/) offers very good support for attaching properties to pages and displaying them in various ways. You write something like `[[status::in progress]]` in the article, and then you can list all those statuses on the main page.

It is a bit of an overkill if the only thing you want is to show the status for a fixed list of pages, but offers a lot of flexibility (e.g. you can automatically order pages by status, or only list those with a given status or whatever).